# Google sheet scripts run slow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am somewhat new to this, so may be I am missing something basic.

Why custom functions in google sheets run so low. For example I have 30 rows with data and I want to delete empty rows. The function only runs within this range but I can see function go line by line in real time.

Shouldn't such simple functions happen in a fraction of a second?

Comment: If you want to speed up the script, try changing the information processing algorithm. Read all the data from the sheet once, process it using multidimensional array methods, and insert the array once into the sheet

Comment: Most likely, you are processing the data line per line, see answer provided below. That should be a great way to tackle the speed issue. Reading the data, filtering then setting values by bulk via `setValues`.

Comment: Thanks @Sergey!

Comment: Thanks @ASyntuBU!

Answer (score 2):

Deleting rows is intensive since it's affecting the shape of the spreadsheet rather than just the values *in* the spreadsheet.  Instead of deleting the rows, maybe have your script get all the values, then filter out the empty rows, then clear the sheet and put the values back.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange('A3:Z');
var values = range.getValues().filter(e=>e[0]);
range.clearContent();
sheet.getRange(3,1,values.length,26).setValues(values);
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.